# SQL Server 2016 - how to date setting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016 (free version). The date camp is set to "yyyymmdd" but I would like that the data can be store in the table like "mmddyyyy".

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

or this using format and cast (to make sure that it's of date data type)

```
 select format(cast(@date as date),'MMddyyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, 

SET DATEFORMAT { format | @format_var }
```

Arguments

format | @format_var
Is the order of the date parts. Valid parameters are mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd, and dym. Can be either Unicode or double-byte character sets (DBCS) converted to Unicode. The U.S. English default is mdy.